# NSWindow color not changing if I am using it as NSSheet. How resolve this issue?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know it seems to be a trivial question however I am facing hard time to find a solution.

Please let me explain what I am doing.

**How I am changing NSWindow background Color**

[image]

I have generated a *User defined runtime attributes* Key **backgroundColor** of type Color for the NSWindow

**Issue**

The above way is working fine however when I am calling the NSWindow as NSSheet then the color of window is not changing.

Please suggest some solution for the issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when an NSWindow is a sheet, It doesn't draw It's background color.

I think a solution to this would be to add a background view to your window and draw the background using this view instead of using the window's backgroundColor property.

Like this [sample app](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/Background%20Sheet.zip).

[image: sample app screenshot showing colored sheet]